# Listen to POST requests, parse-server, node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a self-hosted `parse-server` in AWS EC2. I want to update my database when I receive `POST`notifications from Apple. For that, I created a `cloud function`, but since Apple asks for a `url`to send notifications, I'm not sure how to make my `cloud function` directly accessible via `url` or if I need to create an `endpoint` somewhere (AWS) to receive the notification from Apple and then make a new `httpRequest` or `curl` to my `cloud function`.

I'm looking for any directions or services (AWS) on how to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do anything in AWS. You just need to add the cloudFunction to your main.js

As an example, here is an endPoint called *add3NumbersTogether* . I put this in my main.js file and then I can call this code from iOs (or another client). In iOs I use the Parse iOs SDK to make calls

```
Parse.Cloud.define("add3NumbersTogether", function(request, response) {
  response.success( {request.params.num1 + request.params.num2 + request.params.num3});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although, I need to know how to trigger that function with a url.

Comment: that's not really it, we must also pass parameters.

Comment: See the request.params? Those are parameters that are passed into the call.